# Shadows in Cycles

Tags: rendering, shadows

I have a request. Do you know where I am doing wrong? I have soft shading in the preview, but it's hard after rendering.

[image]

Thank you Tom

Comment: What do you have the View Transform and Look set to under Color Management in the Render settings?

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Look at your viewport shading popover to make sure you use the scene lights and world. Check in your outliner that all your light are visible in the viewport and render. If the issue isn't here, please upload your file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and [edit] your post to include the download link.

Comment: You have a point light disabled in viewport, but enabled in renders.  Check the outliner in the top right :)

Comment: for Allen Simpson

Thank you for the notice. That was it.